# Как эмулировать нажатие клавиши Delete?

Tags: python, python-3.x, автоматизация

Мой код:

```
import win32api, win32con

shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shell.SendKeys("{DELETE}")
shell.SendKeys("{DEL}")
```

при его работе ничего не происходит

что я делаю не так?

Comment: `shell.sendKeys(Keys.DELETE);`, Но он не может работать для удаления входного текста, вы должны использовать `shell.sendKeys(keys.BACKSPACE);`

Answer (score 1):

Есть такой модуль [pyautogui](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui).

Пример ниже введет `'12390'`, после удалит последние две цифры и допишет `'45'`:

```
import time

# pip install pyautogui
import pyautogui

pyautogui.typewrite('12390')

time.sleep(0.5)

pyautogui.press('backspace')        # Вариант клика 1
pyautogui.typewrite(['backspace'])  # Вариант клика 2

pyautogui.typewrite('45')
```